# SP2007 - Security Web Zone

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

Is there a way of having a Web Zone on a sharepoint page that will showing certain, or all, content based on a security group (local to Sharepoint)?

I have a Web Zone content that will have 3 WebParts, 1 for Admin, Contributors, and Users.

Is this best done at the Page level? is there a Web Zone that i can load into the page that will handle this type of setup? or a Web Part that will wrap a contained Web part into this type of setup?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the Audience controls in the web part settings?

if you have defined SP Groups for Admin, Contributor and standard user then all you need to do is specify in the Audience settings which group should see the webpart.

Comment: thank you ill try that....does it give a drop-down select list? or will i have to know the name of the group before entering it?